# prefixText property of a TextField causing layout issues in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am learning flutter and noticed this problem in my app. The app opens a modalBottomSheet when an icon button ('+') is clicked which is present on the appBar. The modal bottom sheet has two textfields in a row. One of the textfields has the property prefixText set on it which is causing it to not align with the other textfield as shown in the images below:

With prefixText:

[image]

Without prefixText:

[image]

Without prefixText with keyboard:

[image]

With prefixText with keyboard:

[image]

Textfield Code:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            maxLength: 50,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              label: Text('Title'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 24),
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            maxLength: 7,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              prefixText: 'Rs. ', //line that is causing this problem
              label: Text('Amount'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How can I solve this? Is it possible to set the fontSize of the prefixText?

It is in landscape orientation if it helps.

Run on: Simulator & Emulator. Problem persists in both.

Flutter version: 3.10.1